# Array element from lua

Tags: lua

I'm making a fivem server. But when i tru to pick the job.grade.name he says No grades.

```
QBShared.Jobs = {
["unemployed"] = {
    label = "Werkloos",
    grades = {
        [0] = {
            name = 'Werkloos',
            payment = 10,
        },
    },
    defaultDuty = true,
},
["police"] = {
    label = "Politie",
    grades = {
        [0] = {
            name = "Politie - Student", **Want to pick this**
            payment = 200,
        },

        [1] = {
            name = 'Aspirant',
            payment = 300,
        },

        [2] = {
            name = 'Agent',
            payment = 400,
        },

        [3] = {
            name = 'Hoofd Agent',
            payment = 400,
        },

        [4] = {
            name = 'Brigadier',
            payment = 400,
        },

        [5] = {
            name = 'Inspecteur',
            payment = 400,
        },

        [6] = {
            name = 'Hoofd Inspecteur',
            payment = 400,
        },

        [7] = {
            name = 'Commissaris',
            payment = 400,
        },

        [8] = {
            name = 'Hoofd Commissaris',
            payment = 400,
        },

        [9] = {
            name = 'Eerste Hoofd Commissaris',
            isboss = true,
            payment = 400,
        },
    },
    defaultDuty = true,
```

So people can type /baan and then the see Baan: Politie
What i want is The must see Baan: Politie - Politie Student

```
QBCore.Commands.Add("baan", "Kijk wat je baan is", {}, false, function(source, args)
local Player = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(source)
TriggerClientEvent('chatMessage', source, "SYSTEM", "warning", "Baan: "..Player.PlayerData.job.label .. ' - ' ..Player.PlayerData.job.grade.name)
```

end)

Someone can help me? Because i want to learn more about lua but dont get this to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Jobs' needs a string key to access it
and 'grades' needs a numerical index

```
Player .PlayerData .Jobs [job] .grades [grade] .name
```

`TriggerClientEvent('chatMessage', source, "SYSTEM", "warning", "Baan: "..Player.PlayerData.job.label .. ' - ' ..Player.PlayerData.Jobs[job].grades[grade].name)`

---

I'm assuming that somehow within your game engine, these values get parsed into PlayerData.  That'll depend on the functions contained within fivem, and that you've used them properly.  Otherwise, to access the raw table data, it's more like this:

```
print( QBShared.Jobs['police'].label )
```

Politie

```
print( QBShared.Jobs['police'].grades[0].name )
```

Politie - Student

```
print( QBShared.Jobs['police'].grades[0].payment )
```

200

---

*if* the game rearranges those during import into PlayerData, it *might* be

`Player.PlayerData[job][grade].name`

but it's very likely it remains in the original syntax illustrated above.